# Start another program after the end of the previous in Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch file to run 3 setup.
But i can't execute them all in the same time, so i'm asking if there is a solution to launch the second setup after the end of the first.

I tried /wait ,/b , call but nothing work.

I have this for the moment :

```
@echo off
start "" ".\01_Drivers\Drivers 2018\NI-DAQmx 18.0 (RunTime 4)\setup.exe"
start ""  /wait ".\01_Drivers\Drivers 2018\NI-VISA 18.0 RTE\setup.exe"
start ""  /wait ".\01_Drivers\Drivers 2018\NI-LabVIEW 18.0 RTE\setup.exe"
exit
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Add `/wait` to the first line as well.

Comment: You can remove `/wait` from the last start line too!